# php specific word in an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have 2 arrays that one contains words and the other words and values. I have the code below that will check one array against the other and will add the values and will return the total. However, if there are common words n the string the code add values for them too.

How can I get the value only for the exact word Green in the example below?
Like in the example below I total should be 3 and not 15.

```
$a_array = array( array("name"=> "Red", "price"=> "2"), 
array("name"=> "Green", "price"=> "3"), 
array("name"=> "Green Leaf", "price"=> "4"), 
array("name"=> "Green Light", "price"=> "8"), 
array("name"=> "Grey", "price"=> "1"), 
array("name"=> "Yellow", "price"=> "11"));


$check = array(Blue, Green, Black, );
$total = 0; foreach ($check as $key => $value): 
foreach ($a_array as $itemKey => $itemValue): 
if (strstr($itemValue['name'], $value)): 
$total += $itemValue['price']; 
continue; endif; endforeach; endforeach;


echo "Total: $total";
```

Comment: please up-vote also. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<?php  
   $a_array = array( array("name"=> "Red", "price"=> "2"), 
   array("name"=> "Green", "price"=> "3"), 
   array("name"=> "Green Leaf", "price"=> "4"), 
   array("name"=> "Green Light", "price"=> "8"), 
   array("name"=> "Grey", "price"=> "1"), 
   array("name"=> "Yellow", "price"=> "11"));

   $check = array('Blue', 'Green', 'Black' );
   $total = 0; foreach ($check as $key => $value): 
   foreach ($a_array as $itemKey => $itemValue): 
   if ($itemValue['name']== $value): // condition is changed here
   $total += $itemValue['price']; 
   continue; endif; endforeach; endforeach;

   echo "Total: $total";
?>
```

Output is: Total: 3

Answer (score 0):

use below code . instead of use `strstr` function to match string use '==' operator.

```
 if ($itemValue['name'] == $value):
```

instead of

```
 if (strstr($itemValue['name'], $value)):
```